# Reading back 0xffff for temperature from I2C BMP085 temp/pressure sensor

Tags: sensor, temperature, i2c

I'm interfacing a Rabbit 5760 CPU to a [Bosch BMP085 sensor](http://www.bosch-sensortec.com/content/language1/downloads/BST-BMP085-DS000-05.pdf) via I2C. Everything is fine except reading the temperature register is reading back 0xffff (see BP_FINISHTEMP case in switch). I can't see why it isn't working. The code is below. Can anyone see what's wrong? The pressure and calibration values read back fine. Thanks if anyone can help.

```
// baro.lib, Barometer related functions

/*** BeginHeader InitBarometer, ReadBarometer */
int InitBarometer(void);
int ReadBarometer(void); // has 4 phases

/*** EndHeader */

// this all comes from the barometer data sheet
struct s_baroparams {
    short ac1;
    short ac2;
    short ac3;
    unsigned short ac4;
    unsigned short ac5;
    unsigned short ac6;
    short b1;
    short b2;
    short mb;
    short mc;
    short md;
} baroparams;
enum {BP_FAIL,BP_STARTTEMP,BP_FINISHTEMP,BP_STARTPRESSURE,BP_FINISHPRESSURE}  

BarometerPhase;
unsigned long LastBarometerStartTime;
long baro_ut;
long baro_up;

// Returns TRUE if successful, else FALSE
int InitBarometer(void) {
    char *ptmp;
   char hi,lo;
    int i;

    assert(Stack_Low());

    BarometerPhase = BP_FAIL;
    // OLD CODE THAT USED TO USE PORT B FOR I2C
    // cannot use i2c_init because it assumes port D
    // so these lines sorta replace it
    // PB1,PB3,PB5 are SCL, SDA, and XCLR on the barometer
    // we want pb1 and pb3 to be low inputs to let the pullups work, and pb5 to be low, output, then high output

// These pins assigned to portD for the HS4, used to be port B
    /*
    WrPortI(PDDR,&PDDRShadow,0); // all low to start
    WrPortI(PDDDR,&PDDDRShadow,(1<<5)); // all inputs except pd5
    WrPortI(PDDR,&PDDRShadow,PDDRShadow|(1<<5)); // now pd5 is high
    */

    // pull baro. sensor out of reset by setting XLR high (XLR is port D bit 1).
    // This assumes we'll want it out of reset before initting the I2C interface,
    // VERIFY THIS
    BitWrPortI(PDDDR,&PDDDRShadow,1,1);
    BitWrPortI(PDDR,&PDDRShadow,1,1);

i2c_init();

   // i2c_clocks_per_us = (int)(19200L*32*freq_divider/1000000L);

   // evil evil hack here
   ptmp = (char *)&baroparams.ac1;
   for (i=0;i<11;i++) {    // 11 is number of 2-byte values in baroparams above
    // start condition
       if (i2c_start_tx()) {
        return FALSE;
       }
       // send ef
       if (i2c_write_char(0xee))
        return FALSE;
       if (i2c_write_char(0xaa+i*2))
        return FALSE;
       if (i2c_start_tx()) {
        return FALSE;
       }
       if (i2c_write_char(0xef))
        return FALSE;
       if (i2c_read_char(&hi))
        return FALSE;
       i2c_send_ack();
       if (i2c_read_char(&lo))
        return FALSE;
       i2c_send_nak();
       // stop condition
       i2c_stop_tx();
      *ptmp++ = lo;
      *ptmp++ = hi;
}
BarometerPhase = BP_STARTTEMP;
   LastBarometerStartTime = 0;

   return TRUE;
}

// Return -1 if failed, 0 if success
int ReadBarometer()    {
    unsigned long dt;
//   unsigned char hi,lo,xlo;
   union { long l; unsigned char uc[4]; } u;
   long x1,x2,x3,b3,b5,b6,b7,t,p;
   unsigned long b4;
   long b6x;

    assert(Stack_Low());

   switch (BarometerPhase) {
    case BP_FAIL:
          return -1;
    case BP_STARTTEMP:
           if (i2c_start_tx()) {
            return -1;
           }
          if (i2c_write_char(0xee))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_write_char(0xf4))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_write_char(0x2e))
             return -1;
          i2c_stop_tx();
         BarometerPhase = BP_FINISHTEMP;
         LastBarometerStartTime = MS_TIMER;
         break;
    case BP_FINISHTEMP:
          u.l = 0;
        dt = MS_TIMER - LastBarometerStartTime;
         if (dt < 6) break;

         if (i2c_start_tx()) {
            return -1;
           }
          if (i2c_write_char(0xee))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_write_char(0xf6))
            return -1;
           if (i2c_start_tx()) {
            return -1;
           }
          if (i2c_write_char(0xef))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_read_char(&u.uc[1]))
            return -1;
          i2c_send_ack();
          if (i2c_read_char(&u.uc[0]))
            return -1;
          i2c_send_nak();
          i2c_stop_tx();
        baro_ut = u.l;
        BarometerPhase = BP_STARTPRESSURE;
         break;
    case BP_STARTPRESSURE:
           if (i2c_start_tx()) {
            return -1;
           }
          if (i2c_write_char(0xee))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_write_char(0xf4))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_write_char(0x34+(BARO_OSS<<6)))
            return -1;
          i2c_stop_tx();
         BarometerPhase = BP_FINISHPRESSURE;
         LastBarometerStartTime = MS_TIMER;
         break;
      case BP_FINISHPRESSURE:
        u.l = 0;
        dt = MS_TIMER - LastBarometerStartTime;
         if (dt < BARO_TIME) break;
           if (i2c_start_tx()) {
            return -1;
           }
          if (i2c_write_char(0xee))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_write_char(0xf6))
            return -1;
           if (i2c_start_tx()) {
            return -1;
           }
          if (i2c_write_char(0xef))
            return -1;
          if (i2c_read_char(&u.uc[2]))
            return -1;
          i2c_send_ack();
          if (i2c_read_char(&u.uc[1]))
            return -1;
          i2c_send_ack();
          if (i2c_read_char(&u.uc[0]))
            return -1;
          i2c_send_nak();
          i2c_stop_tx();
         baro_up = u.l >> (8-BARO_OSS);

        // need lots of work here
        x1 = ((baro_ut-baroparams.ac6)*baroparams.ac5) >> 15;
          x2 = (((long)baroparams.mc)<<11)/(x1+baroparams.md);
          b5 = x1+x2;
          t = (b5+8)>>4;
    //          sprintf(g_Temperature,"%ld",t);
        // append units
        gf_Temperature = t / 10.0;
        if (gConfiguration.tempUnits == Celcius) {
            sprint_fixedpoint(g_Temperature,t,1);
            strlcat(g_Temperature, "&deg;C", sizeof g_Temperature);
        }
        else {
            sprint_fixedpoint(g_Temperature, CelciusToF(t), 1);
            strlcat(g_Temperature, "&deg;F", sizeof g_Temperature);
        }
        b6 = b5 - 4000;
        b6x = (b6*b6)>>12;
         x1 = (baroparams.b2*b6x)>>11;
         x2 = (baroparams.ac2*b6)>>11;
        x3 = x1 + x2;
         b3 = ((((long)baroparams.ac1*4+x3)<<BARO_OSS)+2)/4;

         x1 = (baroparams.ac3*b6)>>13;
         x2 = (baroparams.b1*b6x)>>16;
         x3 = ((x1+x2)+2)>>2;
         b4 = baroparams.ac4*(unsigned long)(x3+32768)>>15;
         b7 = ((unsigned long)baro_up-b3)*(50000>>BARO_OSS);
         if (b7 < 0x80000000)
             p = (b7*2)/b4;
         else
             p = (b7/b4)*2;
         x1 = (p>>8)*(p>>8);
         x1 = (x1*3038)>>16;
         x2 = (-7357*p)>>16;
         p = p + ((x1+x2+3791)>>4);

        gf_Pressure = p / 100.0;
        // append units
        if (gConfiguration.baroUnits == Millibars) {
            sprint_fixedpoint(g_Pressure,p,2);
            strlcat(g_Pressure, " millibars", sizeof g_Pressure);
        }
        else {
            sprint_fixedpoint(g_Pressure, millibarsToInHg(p), 2);
            strlcat(g_Pressure, " inHg", sizeof g_Pressure);
        }
        BarometerPhase = BP_STARTTEMP;
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

---

Bosch BMP085 sensor [datasheet](http://www.bosch-sensortec.com/content/language1/downloads/BST-BMP085-DS000-05.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

This started as a comment but it really is an answer:

You seem to have far more code than is necessary for debugging a basic hardware function. You should be first attempting to be sure you know how to operate the IC correctly. Asking people to wade through and debug code which adds layers on top of basic functionality is a far harder way of doing things. So -

Simplify what you are doing to the the bare minimum so you are

- testing hardware functionality
- and your understanding of it.

Only once you are sure of this should you add layers of complexity.

It's reasonably likely that you are doing something wrong in the processing rather than basic data inputing. Your code needs to address the minimum possible  hardware interaction needed to obtain the core signals.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting a bus analyzer to the I2C? Just because the Microprocessor is saying it is reading 0xFFFF doesn't mean that's what's on the I2C bus. If a sensor is not transmitting data to the bus you will get all 1's because of the pull-up resistors.

Using a bus analyzer would help you determine if the 0xFFFF is coming from the Rabbit or the BMP085. It's also possible that the 0xFFFF may be some kind of error code from the BMP085.